# Python - reference object in memory by address

Tags: python

This is kind of a silly question, but I'm just curious about it.

Suppose I'm at the Python shell and I have some database object that I query.  I do:

`db.query(queryString)`

The query returns a response `<QueryResult object at 0xffdf842c>` or something like that.

But then I say "Oh! I forgot to put `result = db.query(queryString)` so that I can actually use the result of my query!"

Well isn't there some method that just lets me reference the object in memory?

Something like `result = reference('<QueryResult object at 0xffdf842c>')`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do:

```
>>> result=_
```

at the shell. `_` represents the last calculated object.

Example:

```
>>> iter(range(10))
<listiterator object at 0x10ebcccd0>
>>> result=_
>>> result
<listiterator object at 0x10ebcccd0>
>>> list(result)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

You can also see the string representation of the object (if the object type supports that) by typing `repr(_)`

Comment: oh, `_` is the most recently returned object?

Comment: @John Peter Thompson Garcés: Yes

Comment: So, what if I want the result of some previous expression?  I just read that in IPython you can do `_2`, `_3`, etc.  But is there anything that can do this in the standard Python shell?

Comment: @John Peter Thompson Garcés: I am pretty sure the default Python shell only stores a single object output (unlike iPython...)